# How do I use a string array and scanner in a while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I was told to turn a functional auto for loop that goes through all the rooms in the house into a while loop that allows the user to type what room they go into next.

The issue is you need to use the array and scanner in the while loop and I am struggling to think on how to do this, the array somehow needs to be part of the condition in the while loop and I need to be able to type what room I want to access in the array without modifying the string values in my rooms array.

Am I overthinking this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String[] rooms; 
        rooms = new String[] {"hall", "kitchen", "lounge", "bedroom", "bathroom"};
        String room = "";
        String lastRoom = "";
        room = myInput.next();
        while (! room.equals("exit")){
            System.out.print("Here we are ");
            if (room.equals(lastRoom)) {
                System.out.print("back ");
            }
            System.out.print("in the " + room + ". ");
            switch (room){
                case "kitchen": System.out.println("Can you smell the coffee? "); break;
                case "lounge": System.out.println("You can fit a nice corner sofa in here! "); break;
                case "bedroom": System.out.println("This is where all the action and snoring happens. "); break;
                case "bathroom": System.out.println("The bath also has a shower for quick washes. "); break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            lastRoom = room;
            room = myInput.next();
        }
        myInput.close();
    }
```

Technically it works but I am not using the array at all and I need to make this do the same thing but using the array rather than using an empty string variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference array values via [index] where index starts from 0.

Instead of switch use if else statement (you can't use switch with array value since switch requries compile time constants), like so:

```
if (room.equals(rooms[1])) {
     System.out.println("Can you smell the coffee? ");
} else if (room.equals(rooms[2])) {
   System.out.println("You can fit a nice corner sofa in here! ");
} // ...
```

Comment: So I was overthinking it. I was trying to make the array part of the condition for the while loop, I guess I got tunnel vision over this.